# Jquery showing selected elements

Tags: jquery, underscore.js

I have designed a template using **underscore.js** that iterates over a *paginate* variable and displays respective number of links. Code is:

```
<% var paginate= 10 %>

<table>
    <tr>
        <td><a href="">&lt;</a></td>
        <% for(var i=0; i < paginate; i++){ %>

            <td>
                <a class="someclass" href="<%= i%>"><%= i%></a>
            </td>

        <% }%>
        <td><a href="">&gt;</a></td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

I am getting this result after invocation:

[image]

I want to **display the links in chunks of 5**. Like "< 0 1 2 3 4 >" or "< 4 5 6 7 8 9>".

How can I show only 5 and hide the rest of them using jQuery? Please advise.

Comment: `<% for(var i=0; i < 5; i++){ %>` ? alternatively, you could perhaps give each `a` tag a class or id and select that using jquery and hide it?

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I got some insight but still not able to go all the way through. I can give each of them a class or id, still how do I select only 5 of those?

Comment: you can use :gt and :lt filter

Comment: Why dont you just do `<% var paginate= 5 %>`?

Comment: The value of paginate is hard-coded right now. It will be much greater than that. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have a look at this [solution](http://jsfiddle.net/z5sUB/2/). This is a demo solution, you can improve it to match your requirement.

```
var slide  = 0;
$('.page:gt(4)').hide();
$('.prev').hide();
if(len < 5) {
    $('.next').hide();
}

$('.prev a').on('click', function(e){
    e.preventDefault();

    slide--;
    var heigher= slide * 5 + 5;
    var lower = slide * 5;

    $('.page:gt(' + (heigher-1) + ')').hide();
    $('.page:lt(' + (heigher) + '):gt(' + (lower) + ')').show();
    $('.page:eq(' + (lower) + ')').show();

    if(slide == 0){
        $('.prev').hide();
    }
    if(len > 5){
        $('.next').show();
    }
});

$('.next a').on('click', function(e){
    e.preventDefault();

    var lower = slide * 5 + 5;
    slide++;
    var heigher = slide * 5 + 5;

    $('.page:lt(' + lower + ')').hide();
    $('.page:lt(' + (heigher) + '):gt(' + (lower-1) + ')').show();

    if(heigher >= len){
        $('.next').hide();
    }
    $('.prev').show();
});
```

I've an update solution [here](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/z5sUB/4/), it has a much better jQuery code I believe.

Comment: Thanks for the awesome reply. There is one problem though. I am using the exact same code and I am unable to select the like via jQuery. I tried `$('.page a').click(function(e){})` , gave it an id and tried `$('a#clickLink').click(function(e){})`. Any suggestions on how to pick the link with jQuery.

Comment: There was error in my code. It is working fine now. Thanks for the code. Cheers!!!